# Multiple grouping using argparser in python

Tags: python, argparse

Hi I want to group vars in the way I pass in command line. Consider following example.

```
shell> python cli.py -a 1 -b 23 -b 3 -a 2 -b 7
```

So the grouping should happen as all b's before 2nd 'a' should belong to first 'a' and last 'b' belongs to last 'a'

So final result after parse output should be

```
first a {value:1,b:[23,3]}
Second a {value:2,b:[7]}
```

I tried multiple ways of using argparse to build it, but could not find logic to do it.

Comment: People have asked for variations on this in other SO, but no, there's nothing in `argparse` tailored for this.  You can specify `action='append'`, but that just collects all the `a` in one list, and `b` in another.  Normally there isn't any interaction or dependency between arguments.   You have to define custom `Action` class(es) to create interactions - or wait for some kind soul to do that for you :). But it may be easier to process `sys.argv` directly.

Comment: Yes I can implement @GustavD logic using sys.argv. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and i solved it by using two arrays for a's and b's. In python lists are great, since you can store lists of lists easily. When the parser encounters variable a,

The big list looks like

[[a1]], when b1 and b2 are encountered,

[[a1, b1, b2]], a2 encountered,

[[a1, b1, b2], [a2]], and so on and so forth.

Do you like this solution?